# a function that is not $o(n)$ but also no $\Omega(n)$

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I need to find a positive function like this

$$f(n) \neq O(n)\, \text{ and } f(n) \neq \Omega(n)?$$

We can define a function that for infinite number of input will take O(n^2) and for infinite number of input will take $O(1)$ [for example]. Example for a function like this :

```
f(n) = if(n mod2 == 0) => n^2, else => 1
```

But in computer science we always consider the worst case, what make the function complexity to be n^3 and we are not meet the question requirements.

Am I right? do you have other soultion? thanks

Comment: There are actually [two different versions of $\Omega()$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Which one are you using?

Comment: Why do your title and your first sentence ask different questions?